# Как сделать по умолчанию чтобы текст в textarea полностью отображался?

Tags: jquery

У меня на странице есть много textarea и во всех разное количество текста, я нашла код который растягивает высоту textarea количеству текста в нем, но показывает весь текст только после того как в textarea вписать хотя бы одну букву (попробуйте в примере поймете о чем я). Как сделать по умолчанию чтобы текст полностью отображался? Зарание спасибо)

```js
jQuery.each(jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]'), function() {
  var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;
 
  var resizeTextarea = function(el) {
    jQuery(el).css('height', 'auto').css('height', el.scrollHeight + offset);
  };
  jQuery(this).on('keyup input', function() { resizeTextarea(this); }).removeAttr('data-autoresize');
});
```

```css
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea data-autoresize>Lacus eros aptent suspendisse etiam torquent imperdiet aptent ac ligula egestas est bibendum. Dictumst egestas himenaeos, semper porttitor platea at quis eget eget. Rutrum inceptos magna pharetra dolor congue magnis inceptos, augue laoreet nisl nec euismod? Venenatis hac porta tincidunt volutpat turpis vestibulum euismod donec </textarea> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Простой [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/1bq5mv6L/)

Comment: @InDevX Да пример хороший, но нужно чтобы не за id а за textarea

Comment: замените `var text = document.getElementById('textarea');` на  `var text = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с минимальным изменением вашего кода, это будет так:

```js
jQuery.each(jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]'), function() {
  var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;
 
  var resizeTextarea = function(el) {
    jQuery(el).css('height', el.scrollHeight + offset);
  };
  /* Выше же создана переменная-функция. Вот и можно вызывать его сразу при загрузке */
  resizeTextarea(this); /*Добавив this в параметр, который будет указывать на каждое поле*/
  jQuery(this).on('input', function() { 
     resizeTextarea(this); /* ровно также вызывается функция во время печати */
  /* Здесь убрал removeAttr, потому что он не был нужен... */
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none; /* (!) */
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<textarea data-autoresize>Lacus eros aptent suspendisse etiam torquent imperdiet aptent ac ligula egestas est bibendum. Dictumst egestas himenaeos, semper porttitor platea at quis eget eget. Rutrum inceptos magna pharetra dolor congue magnis inceptos, augue laoreet nisl nec euismod? Venenatis hac porta tincidunt volutpat turpis vestibulum euismod donec </textarea>
<textarea data-autoresize>Lacus eros aptent suspendisse etiam torquent imperdiet aptent ac ligula egestas est bibendum. Dictumst egestas himenaeos, semper porttitor platea at quis eget eget. Rutrum inceptos magna pharetra dolor congue magnis inceptos, augue laoreet nisl nec euismod? Venenatis hac porta tincidunt volutpat turpis vestibulum euismod donec </textarea>
```

P.s. 

• Если на странице не используется другая библиотека, в которой есть `$`, то везде можно (нужно) подменить `jQuery` на `$`. Так просто легче писать... а слово jQuery придумано, чтобы заменить $ и не конфликтовать с другими библиотеками.

• data-autoresize так-то тоже можно заменить на какой-нибудь класс. Или, если на странице не будет других textarea, а все должны подчиняться этому скрипту, сразу записать $('textarea').

```js
$.each($('textarea'), function() {
  var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight; 
  var resizeTextarea = function(el) {
    $(el).css('height', el.scrollHeight + offset);
  }  
  resizeTextarea(this);
  $(this).on('input', function() { 
     resizeTextarea(this);
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none;
  overflow:hidden;  
  width: 450px; border: 2px solid orange; margin: 5px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea>Lacus eros aptent suspendisse etiam torquent imperdiet aptent ac ligula egestas est bibendum. Dictumst egestas himenaeos, semper porttitor platea at quis eget eget. Rutrum inceptos magna pharetra dolor congue magnis inceptos, augue laoreet nisl nec euismod? Venenatis hac porta tincidunt volutpat turpis vestibulum euismod donec </textarea>

<textarea>Lacus eros aptent suspendisse etiam torquent imperdiet aptent ac ligula egestas est bibendum. Dictumst egestas himenaeos, semper porttitor platea at quis eget eget. Rutrum inceptos magna pharetra dolor congue magnis inceptos, augue laoreet nisl nec euismod? Venenatis hac porta tincidunt volutpat turpis vestibulum euismod donec </textarea>
```

P.P.s. В общем случае, если есть какая-нибудь функция:

```
var bubu = function () { ... }

/* или */

function bubu() { ... }

/* то его можно вызывать сразу при загрузке скрипта, так: */

bubu();
```